# Are "$x=4$" and "$x=\{4\}$" equivalent ways of expressing the solution set of an equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Someone showed me the video ["12 - Equations and Domain of Variables, Part 1"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeZZeGG2XVk) by YouTuber Math and Science, and in this video they define a set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and wish to solve the equation $x+5=9$ for $x$ in the given set. The way this is done is of no issue, however at the end when giving the solution they try to give the solution set over the domain as the (singleton) set $\{4\}$, but as well as writing $x=4$ they also write

$x=\{4\}$,

Defining $x$ to be the entire set (by the looks of it) when they want to say that $x$ can be equal to any element in the set to be a solution. Based on the use of $x$ as a real number this seems incorrect, is there any basis or notation shortcut here, because this seems completely the opposite of the correct use of the equals sign.

Here's a screenshot from timestamp $8:49$:

[image]

Comment: It should be either $x=4$ or "the solution set is $\{4\}.$"

Comment: I believe you would want to write $x \in \{4\}$.  For example if we know $x^2=1$ we can say $x \in \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like a typo for $x \in \{4\}$, since the correct notation is used in $x \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: Yes... I would say that "$x = \{4\}$" is simply incorrect and wrong.

Comment: Hmm, just watched the video. Not sure I like the instructor.  I think he is abusing the commonality of language.   When we say "what is the solution" we are often casual in saying the solution is $4$ and the solution is $\{4\}$ and casual is saying the solution is $x$ is $4$ and $x$ is in the set $\{4\}$ and he goes into great detail setting up we need to distinguish exactly what the language means.... and then he gets ambiguous.  That's a no-no in my book.

Comment: If the equation were $(x-3)^2=4$ so that we can answers of $1$ or $7$.  We can say a variety of things:  "The solutions are $1$ and $7$" (here it understood we are referring to possible values of $x$).  "The solution is either $1$ or $7$" (ditto, but here we are acknowledging that $x$ is a single number and it can be one or the other but not some quantum ghost of both). The solutions are $x=1$ or $x=7$. Correct and more formal. $x=1,7$ That's informal and not really correct but not wrong. It means $x\in\{1,7\}$ and I think that is where the instructor was going with $x=4\iff x=\{4\}$ :(

Comment: @fleablood makes sense, sometimes you get lazy lecturers who write stuff like 'we check $x=1,2,3....$ to signify for each $x=1$, $x=2$, etc but If you are going to use equals and literally call it a 'set' where the equality of sets have been defined then I don't know what he's doing.